# How do I keep last Nth properties from a javascript object (fixed queue)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js

I have an object representing a queue and I want to keep last nth elements from it (fixed size).

```
var m = {};
m["t1"] = {  a: "t1", b: "t1" };
m["t2"] = {  a: "t2", b: "t2" };

......
......
m["tn-1"] = {  a: "tn-1", b: "tn-1" };
m["tn"] = {  a: "tn", b: "tn" };
```

In this example, I want to keep last N and delete the rest.

What is the simple solution ? Can be done with underscore js ?

As"@AlexK noticed, "The order of a for..in object is technically not guaranteed to match the order of addition

EDIT:

I found one solution:

```
m2= {};

_.each(_.last(_.keys(m), size), function(key){
   m2[key] = m[key];
});

m= m2;
```

The problem or the question is if this has a memory leak , what happens with the unused items ?

Comment: Cant you just loop from reverse order and remove all elements expect 1st and second(i mean last 2 values) ?

Comment: The order of a for..in object is technically not guaranteed to match the order of addition

Comment: If you keep the last 2, what do you want to happen when you add a new {a:b} ? Store it before the last 2 or after?

Comment: after, it will be a tn+1

Comment: look at my last solution, keepWhereTIsSuperiorAt(pos,obj), it will be ok with the disorder of objects.

Comment: yeah , but the t1...tx it's just a naming in this example :)

Comment: Your update does not look to have any likely memore leaks, but it has the issue that Alex K suggested.  There is no guarantee that the order of addition matches the order of iteration.  You will probably need to deal with converting the indices to integers and then removing the older ones.

Comment: If `m` is supposed to be used as a queue, why don't you use an `Array` instead (with super `shift`, `slice`, `splice` methods)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a potential native way that keeps name indexing/keys but tracks the order of addition which is required if your not using a true array.

`trimToLast` discards the top items and adjusts the index of the remaining ones.

It uses `a` as the key and replaces any existing item in-place with the same value.
Subsequent additions appear at the end of the object.

```
function Q() {
    this.length = 0;
    this.items = {};
};
Q.prototype.add = function(a, b) {
    this.items[a] = {index: typeof this.items[a] === "undefined" ? this.length++ : this.items[a].index, a: a, b: b};
    return this;
}
Q.prototype.trimToLast = function(keepLast) {
    this.length -= keepLast;
    for (var i in this.items) {
        if (this.items[i].index < this.length) {
            delete this.items[i];
        } else {
           this.items[i].index -= this.length; 
        }
    }
    this.length = keepLast;
}

var q = new Q();
q.add("t1", "t1").add("t2", "t2");
q.add("t3", "t3");
q.add("t4", "t4");

q.trimToLast(2);

q.add("t5", "t5");

for (var i in q.items)
     console.log(i, ": #" + q.items[i].index + " of " + q.length, q.items[i]);
```

For

```
t3 : #0 of 3 Object {index: 0, a: "t3", b: "t3"} 
t4 : #1 of 3 Object {index: 1, a: "t4", b: "t4"}
t5 : #2 of 3 Object {index: 2, a: "t5", b: "t5"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, that is what you want if you name ALL THE TIME your indexes like tXXXX where XXXX is a number :

```
function keepWhereTIsSuperiorAt(number,obj)
{
    for (var property in obj) {
        if(property.substring(1) <= number)
            delete obj[property];       
    }
}

keepWhereTIsSuperiorAt(2,m);
console.log(m);
```

Comment: This would require the calcluation of the correct base number, which would still involve checking all the indices.  I suppose if we know for certain that all indices would always be added, and we know what the latest one added was, this would work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it'd be much easier if you'd just use an array instead of an object, because you can take advantage of the native `splice()` method. But to answer your question:

```
delete m.t1;
delete m.t2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

```
var keepTopFnBuilder = function(count, makeSortKey) {
    return function(obj) {
        var keys = _.sortBy(_.map(_.keys(obj), function(key) {
            return {key: key, sortKey: makeSortKey(key)};
        }), "sortKey");
        _.each(_.first(keys, Math.max(0, keys.length - count)), function(key) {
            delete obj[key.key];
        });
    };
};

var m = {};

var keepTop = keepTopFnBuilder(5, function(key) {return +key.substring(1);});
```

Whenever `keepTop(m)` is called, it will strip out all but the top five elements from `m` based upon the integer stored as the characters after the first in the property name.

The main function in here is somewhat more generic in that it allows you to choose how to turn the indices into a sort keys, and lets you choose how many to keep.  It returns a function that you can then call on your object whenever you add new elements (or as often as you like, I suppose.)

You can see it at work at http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/4M3L4/